# Show newly data using Ajax and jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am using Laravel, I have a following data view

```
<div class="content-inside-main">
        <div class="content-inside" id="content-inside-feedback">
            <div class="row header-content space-div">
                <div class="col-lg-1"><h5>#</h5></div>
                <div class="col-lg-1"><h5>Member Id</h5></div>
                <div class="col-lg-4"><h5>Question</h5></div>
                <div class="col-lg-4"><h5>Reply</h5></div>
                <div class="col-lg-1"><h5>Replied by</h5></div>
                <div class="col-lg-1"><h5>Options</h5></div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <hr class="line-div"/>
            </div>

            <?php
            $questions= \App\Question::all();
            ?>

            <?php
            foreach ($questions as $question):
            $id = $question->id;
            $member_id = $question->user_id;
            $body = $question->message;
            $status=$question->replied;
            $reply=$question->reply;
            $user_id=$question->replied_id;

            $member=\App\Member::find($member_id);
            $m_id=$member->id;
            $m_name=$member->nick_name;
            $m_reg_time=$member->reg_time;
            $m_unreg_time=$member->unreg_time;
            $m_status=$member->unreg;
            $m_group_id=$member->group;

            $group=\App\Group::find($m_group_id);
            $m_group_name=$group->name;

            if($id != NULL) {
            ?>

            <div class="row content-messages" >
                <input type="hidden"  id="count" value="{{$id}}"/>
                <div class="col-lg-1"><?php echo $id; ?></div>
                <div class="col-lg-1"><?php echo $member_id; ?></div>
                <div class="col-lg-4"><?php echo $body; ?></div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <?php
                    if($status == 0){
                    ?>
                    <div class="according-form-container" id="reply-feedback-form_<?php echo $id; ?>">
                        <a class="btn-link show-add-form-div" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#reply-feedback-form_<?php echo $id; ?>" href="#reply-feedback-form_content_<?php echo $id; ?>" >
                            Reply
                        </a>

                        <div id="reply-feedback-form_content_<?php echo $id; ?>" class="collapse collapse-add-form">

                            <form class="form" id="reply-feedback_<?php echo $id; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="addreply">
                                {{csrf_field()}}
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="description">Message: </label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="{{$id}}"/>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="member_id" id="member_id" value="{{$member_id}}"/>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" value="{{Auth::id()}}"/>
                                        <textarea name="description" id="feedback-message_<?php echo $id; ?>"  class="input-block-level" required></textarea>
                                        <br/><br/>
                                        <button id="submitfeedback_<?php echo $id . '_' . $member_id; ?>" type="submit" class="btn feedback-reply-submit-btn">Send</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </form>
                            <div id='preview_feedback_<?php echo $id; ?>'>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <?php
                    } else {?>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">{{$reply}}</div>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>

                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-1">
                    <?php
                    if($user_id != null){
                        $user_name= DB::table('admin')->where('id',$user_id)->value('name');
                        echo $user_name;

                    }else {
                        echo 'None';
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-1">
                    <button id="view_member" name="view_member" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view_memeber"
                            >View
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr class="line-div" />
            <?php
            }
            endforeach;
            ?>
            <div id="show"></div>
        <div class="text-center navigation-paginator" id="paginator" >
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have another application.It fill question table anytime.I want to do If question table have new records,show them in this page without refreshing.

Like following screenshots:

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ny0w4.jpg)

[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WO19n.jpg)

Comment: 1. Try to avoid using `model` inside `view` you have controller for that
2. You need an ajax to be called with interval, that will check for new or edited records


Other option is to use socket + Laravel + Redis so socket will push to client updated info (but is more complicated to implement)

Comment: how to do that ? I have not clear idea

Comment: take a look here https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/using-ajax-for-real-time-update-in-laravel?page=1

Answer (score 1):

You could send periodical ajax calls and then compare the results with the data you already have to add the new values. It could be something along this lines:

```
function query() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'your/url',
    success: function(data) {
      var loadedValues = JSON.parse(data).values;
      // Iterate only in the new values
      for(i = existingValues.length; i < loadedValues.length; i++) {
        $("#content-inside-feedback").append(/*HTML you want to add*/);
      }
    }
  });
  setTimeout(executeQuery, 5000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  // First call, then it will be called periodically
  setTimeout(query, 5000);
});
```